# Polymorphism, issue on my program

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I've been looking around and even though I have found some answers for some reason I can't seem to grasp the concept which is obviously causing a problem in my code.

I have this:

```
public static Contact createContact() {

    Contact contact = null;

    if (ContactUI.getRdb_acquaintance().isSelected()) {
        contact = new Acquaintance();
    } else if (ContactUI.getRdb_friend().isSelected()) {
        contact = new Friend();
        //contact.setStr_telMobile(ContactUI.getTxt_telMobile().getText());
    } else {
        contact = new Family();
        //contact.setStr_telMobile(ContactUI.getTxt_telMobile().getText());
        //contact.setStr_BDay(ContactUI.getTxt_BDay().getText());
    }

    setCommonDetails(contact);

    return contact;
}
```

What I would like is to be able to call the subclasses specific methods `.setStr_telMobile` and `.setStr_BDay` once I have initialized contact as one of its subclasses, but I get an error, I can't access those methods. I have commented the lines in my code.

I thought I was supposed to be able to initialize an object of type Contact to a Friend (subclass of Contact), for example, and get access to the subclass specialized methods and attributes.

Comment: provide the super and sub classes implementations - are the methods you try to define part of the super class? (is Contact a class or interface?)

Comment: No it isn't, as op said. And Contact is a class.

Comment: If your member variable is type of contact, you can only use the methods that are provided by the Contact class.

Comment: Please provide the full compilation error your compiler gives. It will make the answer significantly better, focused and faster.

Comment: Guys...it's obvious, oneteen posted enough code. Seriously

Comment: Also, you're a new programmer, so these mistakes are forgiveable, but still, for future readers, your code has terrible [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)). A better code will be to make the ContactUI (or some other inetrmediate class) return the `Contact` object, without the usage of `if (...) contact = new SomeClass()`. Abstract Factory Pattern is also useful here.

Comment: Thank u all for the comments :)
Thanks for the advice amit - it makes sense yes I understand what U mean. I will do this :)

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment you can't access methods from your subclasses if your instantiate the super class as a member variable.

If you need access to the subclass implementations, than you have to cast.

```
if(contact instanceof Friend){
Friend friend = (Friend) contact;
drinkBeerWith(friend);
}
```

**But**, think about another pattern to implement your code. Maybe polymorphism
isn't the way to do here. An indicator that the concept of your design
may be kind of "wrong" is the use of *instanceof*.

Cheers

Edit:

> What I would like is to be able to call the subclasses specific methods .setStr_telMobile and .setStr_BDay once I have initialized contact

These methods sound as every Contact has kind of a mobile number and 
a birthday, right?

If so, implement the methods as abstract methods in your super class and 
let the subclass overright them

```
public abstract void setStr_telMobile (String mobileNumber);
```

Comment: I am glad that it solved your problem. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of its runtime type, `contact` is a reference of the `Contact` type. As such, the compiler will only allow you to use `Contact`'s methods.

The elegant way to solve this would probably be to use a temporary `Friend` reference to initialize all the members you need and only then assign it to `Contact`:

```
// Snipped
} else if (ContactUI.getRdb_friend().isSelected()) {
    Friend temp  = new Friend();
    temp.setStr_telMobile(ContactUI.getTxt_telMobile().getText());
    contact = temp;
}
// snipped
```

Alternatively, since you know you've assigned `contact` with a `Friend` instance, you could explicitly downcast it to a `Friend` to access its methods:

```
// Snipped
} else if (ContactUI.getRdb_friend().isSelected()) {
    contact  = new Friend();
    ((Friend) contact).setStr_telMobile(ContactUI.getTxt_telMobile().getText());
}
// snipped
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used this downcasting it works perfectly :)